# Autodesk Forge Viewer - GLTF Extension

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, gltf

I am trying to use GLTF extension in forge viewer and open a gltf file by using this extension, but I am getting the error, "The item you are trying to view was not processed completely."

I have tried to run below code, but it is not working properly.

```
       viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById(divId),config3d);
                viewer.start();
                viewer.setTheme('light-theme');
                viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.glTF');

                viewer.loadModel('./belediye.gltf');
```

Answer (score 0):

Loading Forge extension is an async task, we need to use `Promise.then` or `await` to make sure the GLTF extension is loaded.

```js
viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.glTF').then(() => {
  viewer.loadModel('./belediye.gltf');
});

//or 
await viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.glTF');
viewer.loadModel('./belediye.gltf');
```